# Regarding Microsoft Graph API integration in Angular - Spring Boot application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token

Graph API request for which you are seeing the problem
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages

```
Graph API error message


 {
        'error': {
        'code': 'InvalidAuthenticationToken',
        'message': 'Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.',
        'innerError': {
        'request-id': '12e4940d-58af-4d64-98ab-4b3fe645afb8',
        'date': '2020-05-05T13:57:38'
        }
    }
    }
```

Description :
Implementing use case where user can extract emails in our application to download and consolidate attachments to central location using Microsoft graph.

Web application fronted is developed in angular and back-end is developed in spring boot REST API.

Integrating MSAL in angular to authenticate user and get valid tokens.

```
code configuration :
MsalModule.forRoot({
clientID: '83de5e6f-6a5b-48f4-8b64-5e8d6e70aa9d',
authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/',
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/TestLawyer/mail',
cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
// storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
popUp: true,
consentScopes: ['user.read'],
unprotectedResources: ['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/'],
protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
// logger: loggerCallback,
correlationId: '1234',
piiLoggingEnabled: true
})
```

I got the tokens in localstorage. In my solution i want to pass token to our spring boot rest server to extract emails using Microsoft Graph.

can you please help me on this like any tutorials or guidance to implement this use case.

Answer (score 0):

The resource or scope of your token is incorrect.

You should set `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` in the consentScopes.

You can decode your access token in https://jwt.io to see if the token includes the correct resource/scope.